# Allowed File Types for Ajax File Upload

Tags: javascript, ajax

Can anyone help with my query. I want to be able to only allow certain file types to be uploaded to a server using the AjaxFileUpload tool. There is server side validation but I want to validate the file types on the client.

I have used the AllowedFileTypes method of the upload tool like so:

```
<asp:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" runat="server" OnUploadComplete="OnUploadComplete" ThrobberID="Throbber" ClientIDMode="AutoID" AllowedFileTypes="jpg,pdf,docx" />
```

However it only allows pdf files to be uploaded. It won't allow jpg or docx. Is there a reason why or a bug within the AjaxFileUpload tool that anyone is aware of.

Is there another way to do this? I have used the following javascript to validate the file types:

```
var validFilesTypes = ["docx", "jpg", "pdf"];
function ValidateFile() {
  var file = document.getElementById("<%=AjaxFileUpload1.ClientID%>");
  var label = document.getElementById("<%=lblStatus.ClientID%>");
  var path = file.valueOf;
  var ext=path.substring(path.lastIndexOf(".")+1,path.length).toLowerCase();
  var isValidFile = false;
  for (var i=0; i<validFilesTypes.length; i++) {
    if (ext==validFilesTypes[i]) {
        isValidFile=true;
        break;
    }
  }
  if (!isValidFile) {
    label.style.color="red";
    label.innerHTML="Invalid File. Please upload a File with" +
     " extension:\n\n"+validFilesTypes.join(", ");
  }
  return isValidFile;
}
```

and changed the AjaxFileUpload accordingly but it's not working:

```
<asp:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" runat="server" OnUploadComplete="OnUploadComplete" OnClientUploadComplete="ValidateFile" ThrobberID="Throbber" ClientIDMode="AutoID" />
```

Comment: If anyone comes across a similar issue it was a problem with the AjaxControlToolkit and just needed to install a new version.

Answer (score 0):

The feature `AjaxFileUpload` has these allowed file types:

```
<ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" OnUploadComplete="AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete" runat="server" AllowedFileTypes="jpeg,jpg,png,gif,pdf,zip,rar,ZIP,RAR" MaximumNumberOfFiles="5" />
```